# Route on google map

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api

In my application iam using googlemap. in which i am getting sender's latitude and longitude and destination latitude and longitude through Api. which i have taken out in these variables.and the sender and destinations position i want to show with markers or any pins.

```
 ==> sender_lat =value came from API.

    ==> sender_long =value came from API.

    ==> destination_lat =value came from API.

    ==> destination_long =value came from API.
```

How can is how the route on map.

here is the xml code of fragment which i am using in layout.

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: where is your other code?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code for Showing Path On Google Map But its for Android Studio Code

**[Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/ErNaveen/Google-Directions-Android)**

[image]